# negate a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, null

What is the best way to negate a MySQL query, that is, for whatever condition, *force* it to return no records.

I have used `AND 1=0` which seems to work, but i'd be interested to know if there is a standard for something like this.

Comment: You can also just not execute the query?

Comment: @vartec: The point may well be to fetch the table type, i.e. the meta-data for queries like `SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 0`

Comment: @vartec The point is that the script is very large and this is a quick workaround that doesn't require re-factoring the code. Either `1=0` or `AND false` look like valid options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a `false` condition

```
select * from your_table where false
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an inlined predicate that always evaluates to `FALSE` seems the best way to me. By "inlined", I mean that you do not use bind variables. Alternatively, you could use

```
LIMIT 0
```

This has the advantage of being more expressive, but depending on the query optimiser implementation, it might be slower (unverified)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `AND false`. Dont know whether there is any performance difference between the two options.

Answer (score 0):

Your constant expression "1=0" would be evaluated to "false", which is just an alias for "0", prior to executing, so saving MySQL from evaluating the expression by providing the end result would be faster and easier to read:

```
AND FALSE
```